Installation of Kinect SDK in ROS2 Humble to install the driver
I am trying to install the Azure kinect camera driver in ROS2 humble and Ubuntu 22.4, all the information that I can find for the installation of the SDK are for Ubuntu 18.04 and I am not sure if this will align with 22.4 and ROS2 humble. I can only find the driver for Humble but not the SDK. Does anyone have an idea on how to install the SDK for Ubuntu 22.04?
